# How to change current month date to another month

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to select any date and convert it to same date of next upcoming month. For example- I select 1st jun 2014 then it show 1st july 2014 and so on..

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PQfDc/139/)

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' id='txtDate' readonly='true' />
<input type='button' id='btnConvert' value='Convert' /><br/>
Current Date : <span id='spnCurrentDate'></span><br/>
Next Month Date : <span id='spnNewDate'></span>
```

**JS**

```
    $("#txtDate").datepicker({
              changeMonth: true
    });

    $("#btnConvert").click(function(){
    $("#spnCurrentDate").html($("#txtDate").val());
    $("#spnNewDate").html($("#txtDate").val());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI datepicker: add 6 months to another datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137616/jquery-ui-datepicker-add-6-months-to-another-datepicker)

Comment: Note that you can't simply add 1 to months - 2014-01-31 + 1 month -> 2014-02-31 which is converted to 2014-03-03. So if you roll over to the following month, you probably want to set the day to the last of the previous month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/PQfDc/153/)

```
 var date1 = new Date();
 date1.setMonth(date1 .getMonth() + 1);
```

now date1 is an object holding a date which is 1 months later

If you want to set it to the jQuery UI DatePickers, you can do this

```
$("#txtDate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true
});

$("#btnConvert").click(function(){
    var date1 = new Date($("#txtDate").val());
    date1.setMonth(date1 .getMonth() + 1);

    $("#txtDate").datepicker("setDate", date1 );

});
```

Comment: Great, 2014-01-31 + 1 month is 2014-03-03.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just asking how to add one month to a Date object, you can't just add one to the month as 2014-01-31 + 1 month -> 2014-02-31 which is converted to 2014-03-03.

So if you roll over to the following month, you probably want to set the day to the last of the previous month:

```
function addOneMonth(date) {
  var o = new Date(+date);
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);

  // If have rolled over an extra month, set to last
  // day of previous month
  if (date.getDate() != o.getDate()) {
   date.setDate(0);
  }
  return date;
}

addOneMonth(new Date(2014,0,31)); // 2014-02-28
```

or not…

Answer (score -1):

> Try This Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/PQfDc/151/

```
$("#txtDate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    minDate:'0',
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        var d = new Date(selectedDate)
        d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
        $("#txtDate").datepicker("setDate", d );
        $("#spnSelectedDate").text(selectedDate);
        $("#spnNewDate").text($('#txtDate').val());
    }
});


$("#txtDate1").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    minDate:'0' 
});

$("#btnConvert").click(function(){
    var d1 = new Date($("#txtDate1").val());
    var date = d1.getDate();
    var month = d1.getMonth()+1; 
    var year = d1.getFullYear();
    var newDate = month + "/" + date + "/" + year    
    $("#spnSelectedDate1").text($("#txtDate1").val());
    $("#spnNewDate1").text(newDate);
});
```