# In Javascript, Today(31/5) add 1 month will get 1/7

Tags: javascript, date

Today I just found that if I add 1 month on today's date, it returns 1/7.

Can anyone give help on this? Thank you very much.

**Notice: I didn't assign the date to `today` because today is 31/5, and some of you guys is still on 30/5**

```js
var today = new Date(); // today is 31/5 in my timezone
console.log(today);
today.setMonth(today.getMonth() + 1);
console.log(today);
```

Comment: adding a month results in `"2019-06-31T03:43:45.819Z"` which is not possible. So, it's changed to `"2019-07-01T03:43:45.819Z"`

Comment: there is no 31 in June?

Comment: This question has been asked [*many times before*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+add+month+to+a+date). Try [*this answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24361931/257182), or [*this one*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36428762/257182).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a weird way how dates work in JavaScript. According to [documentation in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth#Description):

> The current day of month will have an impact on the behaviour of this
>   method. Conceptually it will add the number of days given by the
>   current day of the month to the 1st day of the new month specified as
>   the parameter, to return the new date. For example, if the current
>   value is 31st August 2016, calling setMonth with a value of 1 will
>   return 2nd March 2016. This is because in 2016 February had 29 days.

In your case when you add a month to 31st of May you get 31st of June. This is not a valid date, and JavaScript translates it to 1st of July