# Get next year with 1 day less in text field [date selected by javascript datepicker]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to get the next year date with less 1 day in"Next Reminder Date " field & date is selected by datepicker in "Joining Date"..base on Joining Datepicker need next year date with 1 day less....please help me

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Visit Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/view.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/view.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/calendar.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
    <style style="text\css">
body {
  background-image: url("formbg.jpg");
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
</style>
<body id="main_body" >
   
 <div id="form_container">
            
                <form id="form_1140107" class="appnitro" method="post" action="">
                    <br><span style="float:right;"><a href="logout.php" ><input type="button" value="Logout" /></a></span>
   <div class="form_description">
                            <center><h2><a>Welcome</a></h2></center>
                            <br>
                          <center></center> 
  </div> 
                     
   <ul >
<li id="li_3" >
  <label class="description" for="element_3">Customer Id</label>
  <div>
   <input id="element_3" name="client" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo(rand(10,100));?>"/> 
  </div> 
</li>    

 <li id="li_1" >
  <label class="description" for="element_1">Joining Date:</label>
  <div>
   <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" /> 
  </div> 
</li>
                            <li id="li_1" >
  <label class="description" for="element_1">Next Renewal Date:</label>
  <div>
                    <input type="text" name="date" value="" /> 
  </div> 
</li>
<li id="li_1" >
  <label class="description" for="element_1">Reminder Date:</label>
  <div>
   <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker3" /> 
  </div> 
</li>
<script>
      
  $(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      var dateAsString = dateText; //the first parameter of this function
      alert(dateAsString);
   }
});
 
  
    });
</script>
                            <!--
--><li id="li_3" >
  <label class="description" for="element_3">Customer Name:</label>
  <div>
   <input id="element_3" name="client" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
  </div> 
  </li> 
<li id="li_3" >
  <label class="description" for="element_3">Mobile No:</label>
  <div>
   <input id="element_3" name="client_name" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
  </div> 
</li> 
<li id="li_4" >
  <label class="description" for="element_4">Email:</label>
  
  <div>
   <input id="element_4_1" name="address" class="element text large" value="" type="text">
   
  </div>
</li>
<li id="li_10" >
  <label class="description" for="element_10">Status</label>
  <div>
  <select class="element select medium" id="element_10" name="status"> 
   <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="Pending" >Pending</option>
<option value="Closed" >Closed</option>

  </select>
  </div> 
</li>  

<li id="li_9" >
  <label class="description" for="element_9">Amount:</label>
  <div>
   <input id="element_9" name="total_cost" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
  </div> 
</li>      <li class="buttons">
       <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="1140107" />
       
                            <center><input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></center><br>
  </li>
                
   </ul>
  </form> 

        </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
Let todays date be x

```
var x = new Date()
x.setFullYear(x.getFullYear()+1)
x.setDate(x.getDate()-1)
console.log(x);
```

Comment: what will happen when it is first day of month?

Comment: Java script takes care of that , try that

Comment: will will like to create a jsfiddle

Comment: not working...i have to select date from joining date and then need next year date based on joining

Comment: Mr.ashok are you there??

Comment: check this one ,,,

Comment: its gives difference of two day...if i remove -2 to -1 then it notworking

Comment: Accept my answer plz!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code. Just run code and see your answer

```
<?php
$StaringDate=date('Y-m-d');

$newEndDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($StaringDate)) . " + 1 year"));

print('Next Reminder Date ' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($newEndDate ))));

?>
```

Comment: how would i get reminder date of back 15 days based on  " next renewal date"

Comment: PHP ? There is no PHP in the question Neil has posted!

Comment: no other language is in question. so i can give answer in any language

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, I worked a little longer than I tought on this one.

I worked on both "next renewal" and "reminder" dates (saw it needed to be 15 days before renewal in comments)

I inspired my answer of two SO answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11139802/2159528
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13459946/2159528

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/2mxkak3w/)

```
$("#datepicker3").datepicker({dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",});
$("#datepicker2").datepicker({dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",});

function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s; }

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
  onSelect: function(dateText, instance) {
        d2 = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat, dateText, instance.settings);
        d2.setDate(d2.getDate() - 1);
    d2.setFullYear(d2.getFullYear() + 1);
    //alert(date2);

    d3 = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat, dateText, instance.settings);
        d3.setDate(d3.getDate() - 15);
    d3.setFullYear(d3.getFullYear() + 1);
    //alert(date2);

    date2 = [pad(d2.getMonth()+1), pad(d2.getDate()), d2.getFullYear()].join('/');
    date3 = [pad(d3.getMonth()+1), pad(d3.getDate()), d3.getFullYear()].join('/');
        //alert (date2);

    $("#datepicker2").datepicker("setDate", date2);
    $("#datepicker3").datepicker("setDate", date3);
    }
});
```